# Can not present and dissmiss viewcontroller without animation and get Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, xamarin.ios

I'm using monotouch in order to developing my ios 7 application.

In the `viewWillAppear` method I use below code for presenting and dismissing the view controller:

```
  public override void ViewWillAppear (bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewWillAppear (animated);

            UIApplication application = UIApplication.SharedApplication;
            if (application.StatusBarOrientation  != UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait )
            {
                UIViewController c = new UIViewController ();
                c.View.UserInteractionEnabled = false;
                PresentViewController  (c,false   ,null  );
                DismissViewController  (false ,null );
            }
//my otyher codes

}
```

While Iamd using `false` for the `animated` parameter but it seems that the `c` viewcontroller is presenting or dismissing with animation. Because I am getting `unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions` error.

I can not use above code in the `viewDidAppear` method and so I do not know how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Never try to change ViewControllers appearence at willAppear state. Instead of changing at willAppear state try to set viewController before it was presented.

Comment: Can you expecify more about "before it wqs presented". How can I do it without making changes in the will appear? Is there any other ways?

Comment: At first: Why You need different viewControllers for different orientations? Can you just change positions of child views? 
If You really need different views try to create 2 different Views and add them as childs to view of Your viewController